# Setter method with exception

Tags: java, class, exception, methods, setter

I have to write a setter method that sets the "Player's name". Thats pretty simple to do but the method also has to check if the name is acceptable (not empty/" "). If the name is empty, it should just ignore the exception and keep going with the program, it shouldn't stop or do any action upon running into that exception.

Heres the code that I decide to use to make that work:

```
public void setName (String newName) {
        name = newName;

        if (newName != null && !newName.isEmpty()) {

        ****//I DONT KNOW WHAT TO WRITE HERE//****
        >>>IT SHOULD ONLY IGNORE THE EXCEPTION<<<
        ****//I DONT KNOW WHAT TO WRITE HERE//****

        }
```

The logic seems okay, but I dont know what to write inside the "IF" statement so it just ignores the exception. It shouldn't display any message or prompt for anything.

Let me know if there is an easier or more appropriate way of doing this, since Im new to Java.

Thanks!

Comment: Tip: Don't use the classic getter and setter method naming, they're reserved for actual getters and setters.

Comment: @Yams What do you mean? This looks like a valid setter to me.

Comment: I would throw an `IllegalArgumentException` instead. Ignoring wrong input will bite you in the behind in the long run.

Comment: It depends on the requirements; we can't really tell from just this one method.

Answer (score 2):

Surely by your requirements you just do nothing for an empty name?

```
public void setName (String newName) {
    if (newName != null && !newName.isEmpty()) {
        name = newName;
    }
}
```

Exceptions (in the sense of things 'thrown' in Java) are not involved here. You check for validity, and ignore what's invalid.

Note: in this case, "ignoring an empty name" means that the previous setting of `name`, if any, is kept.

Answer (score 1):

Your condition already checks to confirm the name is not empty, as in the if block will not be entered if the name is empty. Your function is a void so you don't need to put anything else to handle the empty input.